# Injecting an EF Context in ASP.NET Core app and using migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am currently attempting to use an EF Core dbcontext with a cosmos db on .NET Core 2.2.  My startup cs has a db context injection setup like this:

```cs
var configBuilder= new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

IConfigurationRoot config = configBuilder.Build();

IConfigurationSection configSection = config.GetSection("CosmosSettings");

services.AddDbContext<PiServeDb>(options => options.UseCosmosSql(
    configSection["ServiceEndpoint"], configSection["AuthKey"], configSection["DatabaseName"]
));
```

With the cosmosdb config stuff in the `appsettings.json` file.

The `DbContext` is setup to allow a `DbContextOptions` like so:

```cs
public class PiServeDb : DbContext
{
    public PiServeDb(DbContextOptions<PiServeDb> options)
    : base(options){ }

    public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

and when trying to run an initial migration to update the database I am getting this error consistently:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'. This is often because no database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

I have configured the class to accept this in the constructor so I have no clue what I have done wrong. Is there anything wrong with my setup?

Comment: Did you add the following package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos`?  Also I thought Cosmos did not have a schema, so how would you migrate a schema structure to non schema?

Comment: [There are no migrations in Cosmos DB](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13200) Migrations are built for relational databases. Cosmos DB though doesn't have a schema at the database level so it doesn't need migrations

Comment: The provider [isn't finished](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12086) though and important features like [handling missing properties](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13131) aren't implemented yet.

Comment: Thank you all, I'm new to cosmos and am not entirely familiar with it yet, and wanted to see how well it works with EF Core.  I'll probably just scrap this test project for the time being until the provider is more mature and/or I have more knowledge about how cosmosdb actually works.

Comment: @MasonTurvey no need to do that. You don't *need* migrations in a schemaless database. You can just write new objects with new properties without any modifications. The "misssing properties" issue has to do with how the provider will handle missing properties - imagine trying to deserialize a JSON string that doesn't have all of your entity's attributes. What do you do? You can leave them empty, or you can reject it. Or, you can inspect the string somehow to determine which entity version you should use

Comment: @MasonTurvey this is no different than MongoDB or RavenDB by the way - the creator and reader of a document *don't* need to use the same schema.

Comment: Alright, I'll start tinkering around with it and see what happens when I hook it up to my webapi to see how this bad boy works

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm trying to add new data into the database with a POST, but savechanges throws a NotImplemented exception in the controller's method.  How do I actually add data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190469/discussion-between-mason-turvey-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CosmosDB is schema-less. As such, there's no concept of "migrations". If you add a new property, it just starts saving data for that new property. Granted, there are certain scenarios where you'd like to "migrate" - perhaps you renamed a prop. However, that is more a *data* migration. All the items in your container will need to be updated to move the data from the old member to the new member. EF Core does not currently support this type of scenario, so you'll need to come up with your own strategy to make such changes.

Long and short, you don't create migrations for a CosmosDB store, so that's likely why this doesn't work.

Comment: Handling missing properties is still [work in progress](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13131) though

Comment: So any rescaffolding of the db will need to be done on the cosmos side of things, and can't be done through EF core?

Comment: @MasonTurvey there's no rescaffolding needed. You can change your model any way you want and start writing new documents. Right now you'll have issues if you try to read new properties from *older* documents that don't have them.

Comment: Certain things that would correlate to a schema change in a relational store, yes, will have to handled manually - not everything. Still, you need to realize that CosmosDB is a fundamentally different thing than something like SQL Server. EF Core provides an abstraction layer, but there's not 100% 1-to-1 support between providers. The in-memory provider, for example, doesn't support many things SQL Server provider does, either. Migrations are for relational stores, not NoSQL document stores.